# C programming using methods with defined structs

Tags: c, linked-list

I am very new to C programming. Doing a project for my class involving linked lists. I defined a struct called node which represents a node and it has a value, and a pointer to the next node.

If I want the return type of a method to be of type node, do I have to say

```
struct node* method_name(){}
```

or can I just say

```
node* method_name(){}
```

?

Comment: Write some code, try to solve it. We will help you. We need an example.

Comment: Lets say I am writing a method called create which takes a int value and a pointer to the next node should the method declaration be struct node* create(int value, node* next) or should it be node* create(int value, node*next). 

I declared the structure and the method prototype in the header file which I included in my main file

Comment: `struct` keyword is just needed to define a new datatype as you can find in its definition. To return a pointer to a node, you can just use `node* create(int value, node* next)`

Comment: Please post the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows the problem. Far better than trying to describe the code.

Answer (score 0):

The `struct` is part of the definition of the type, so yes you will have to write `struct node* method_name(){}`

Since this can be a bit tedious, you can also use the `typedef` keyword to set an alias for your type. So if you called the type `struct NODE`, you could then write `typedef struct NODE node` to make `node` be the same as `struct NODE` and then you could write `node* method_name(){}`

Comment: I recommend against using different names for the type with / without `struct`. Just do `typedef struct node node;`.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on whether or not you used `typedef` to define your struct.

If you did it like this:

```
struct node {
    int value;
    struct node *next;
};
```

Then yes, you have to declare the method as `struct node *method_name(){}`

But, if you typedef your struct like this:

```
typedef struct node {
    int value;
    struct node *next;
} node;
```

Then you can declare the function name as `node *method_name(){}`.

The struct itself is of type `struct node`, but the `typedef` allows you to refer to your struct as either `struct node` or just `node`.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using `typedef` such as:

```
typedef struct
{
    /* your structure */
} Node;
```

You can use `Node` without writing `struct`:

```
/* Declare node1 and node2 of type Node */
Node node1, node2;
```

`Node * method_name(void);` returns a pointer of "Node" structure.
If you want to return a Node (not a pointer), you have to code:
`Node method_name(void);`